# what is difference between public var: any = []; and public var: any[] = [];

Tags: typescript

Can anyone help me to understand what is the difference between:

```
public var: any = []; 
// and 
public var: any[] = [];
```

Comment: `any` tells typescript to not check the types. `any[]` tells typescript it's an array, but to not check the types of the elements inside the array. Neither is great; give it a more specific type if possible, such as `string[]` if you'll be putting `string`s in it.

Comment: TypeScript's public `var: any = [];` declares a public class property as an empty array of any type, while `public var: any[] = [];` declares it as an array of any type. The latter specifies an array type and is preferred when initializing an empty array variable.

Answer (score 2):

1. public var: any = []; explicitly sets the type of var to any, which means that it can hold any value of any type;
2. public var: any[] = []; explicitly sets the type of var to an array of any values, which means that it can hold an array of values of any type.

I'm about to try to make an example in order to explain better this concept:

```
public var: any = "hello"; // or it can be public var: any = 12 or something else

public var: any[] = ["hello", 42]; // into the list could be insert any type of object
```